# Can you limit a role to objects that meet a selector?

Tags: kubernetes, authorization

How can we limit a service account to only be able to create, list, delete etc. objects that have a specific label within a given namespace?

---

We have engineered an hierarchy of services (which map to kubernetes namespaces) and components (which are represented by a `persona` label on various objects) and we integrated it with vault in such a way that the secrets you have access to are specific to a service-component pair. This helps segregate things. For example, imagine a team that manages a bunch of deployments, and only some of them handle PII data. We can use that label to selectively grant access to those secrets.

```yaml
# only approximatively k8s objects
---
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: banana
  labels:
    persona: backend
spec: ...
# pods in this deployment have access to banana§backend secrets via a vault sidecar
---
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    persona: frontend
spec: ...
# pods in this deployment have access to banana§frontend secrets via a vault sidecar
```

However, that means we don't want to just create a service account that can manage *all* pods in that namespace — if the secret to that service account gets leaked, an attacker could use it to start a pod with a malicious image and access to PII.

So I'd want to have something like: (please note my knowledge around service accounts, roles and role bindings is extremely limited)

```yaml
# even more approximatively so k8s objects
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: deploy-frontend
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
  selector:
    labels:
      persona: frontend
# even if compromised, this service account cannot access banana§backend secrets
```

It seems like k8s *might* support something vaguely like this e.g. by providing a list of specific resource names ([#](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources)), but that this is otherwise not something k8s supports as of now? or am I missing something?

Is our only alternative setting up a cluster-wide service account with wide access to everything, and then spin up a web service that does its own custom authentication and authorization routine before the token is used? If so, how can we limit the scope of this "god account" as much as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes does not have a way to restrict the **list** verb by object. If you can list a collection, you can read all the objects in that collection.

Maybe one day that will change but right now that is how Kubernetes works in terms of collections and read access. That includes read access to Secrets…

However, if you want to restrict *writes* to objects, you can do that. You can limit the ability to write to specific named objects using:

- an external validating admission webhook
- a (beta) ValidatingAdmissionPolicy
- an authorization webhook

or using carefully-crafted RBAC rules.

---

Something that might help you manage access is the [hierarchical namespaces controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/hierarchical-namespaces/), allowing a team to manage a *set* of namespaces that each have their own restrictions. If your cluster supports ValidatingAdmissionPolicies, you can use those to further delegated access and restrictions on write access (that's quite a complicated topic though).

---

If you want to have one ServiceAccount that can do things, but delegate control of those things, you can make a ServiceAccount in each target namespace with a RoleBinding, and then allow the overall ServiceAccount to impersonate the specific ServiceAccounts. Again, that's quite a complex thing to cover but it's possible.